# Immer does not support setting non-numeric properties on arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immer.js

I'm trying to update a piece of state with an array of data that I'm getting from the server. This is my reducer:

```
const schoolsDataReducer = (state = { data: [] }, action) =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case SET_INITIAL__DATA:
        draft.data = [...action.payload.data]
        break
    }
  })
```

I get this error:

> "Immer does not support setting non-numeric properties on arrays: data"

How am I supposed to store an array of objects?
Are arrays in the state considered bad practice?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that `state` is _actually_ an object at that point in time?  Are you accidentally saving an array from a different action instead of an object with an array inside?

Comment: You're right! I first tried to have the state as an array, instead of as an object with a `data` property being an array. That wasn't working so I updated the reducer but not the tests, so I was still sending an empty array as "previous state". Could you post an answer saying that I'm using an array? I guess people making the same mistake can come here and actually fix their code with your suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens when you pass something not an object for `state`. Make sure `state` is an object.